# Is there a function in JavaScript that replaces text with other text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a login form and I want to when I type in text in the password input it replaces it with `*` but the text is still what you write.

Comment: Looking for `<input type="password">` ?

Comment: Don't validate a password on the client side.

Comment: @eyecatchUp its not my real password

Comment: @Lasse Nonetheless, never validate passwords on the client side. There's no protection at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input. with type `password`

```js
function handle(){
  let value = document.getElementById('password').value
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<input id='password' type='password' onkeyup=handle(this) value=''>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that just simply use `<input>` element with `type="passowrd"`

```html
<input type="password" />
```